# how to change the column name from source by one step in mariadb , c++

Tags: c++, mysql, mariadb

hello i have new problem when the change my version from mysql 5.6 to mariadb 10.2.13

this problem in statement i have the table containing windows column and windows A is word reserved by mariadb in statement and i don't need change name the column because the table is big and my source is big when change this i need edit to all my source and i ask some people i have this answer

```
Instead of changing window to windows, you can simply change it to `window`. (this little change is present on mysql8.0 as well)

Including <mariadb>'s includes isn't 100% required (at must, it's suggested to do so) since the <mysql>'s ones are also added when installing mariadb.

Instead of directly adding the mariadb define in CFLAGS, you can perform a check like mysql --version | grep -c MariaDB.

By default, when linking mariadb, several other dynamic .so are included in the game. (it may be annoying)
```

but i can't understand this please from some people can explain this for me and thanks for all sorry i'm poor in English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you issue an SQL query to MariaDB that contains the column name

`window`

write

`` `window` ``

instead. E.g. if you issue a query

`SELECT * FROM window;`

change it to

`` SELECT * FROM `window`; ``

Yes, you'll need to change it throughout the code.

Comment: the resolve   :               int iLen = snprintf (  szColumns,
        sizeof (szColumns)
        ,
        "id, "
        "owner_id, "
        "\`window\`, "
        "pos, "
        "count, "
        "vnum "
       );